# Rails and RABL sort child by another model that it belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I have 3 models:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buildings
end
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buildings
end
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I need the show the building in each city, but sorted by their company like this:

```
city1
  company1
    building1
    building2
  company2
    building3
city2
  company1
    building5
    building6
    building4
  company2
    building7
    building8
```

I can't figure out how to make the query, or how to use rabl properly to generate this output structure

**EDIT:**

This is what I came up with for the moment:

cities_controlles.rb:

```
def index
  @cities = City.all
  @companies = Company.includes(:buildings)
end
```

index.json.rabl:

```
collection @cities
attributes :id, :name
node :companies do |city|
  @companies.map do |company|
    { id: company.id, name: company.name, buildings:
     company.buildings.map do |building|
       if building.city_id == city.id
         { id: building.id, name: building.name }
       end
     end.compact
   }
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

There is many ways to do it depending of how rezult should be used.

**First way:**

```
SELECT 
    cities.name, companies.name, buildings.name
FROM
    cities
LEFT JOIN
   companies ON companies.city_id = city.id
LEFT JOIN 
    buildings ON buildings.city_id = city.id
ORDER BY
    cities.name, companies.name, buildings.name
```

Rezult should be smth like that:

```
city1 | company1 | building1
city1 | company1 | building2
city1 | company2 | building3
city2 | company1 | building4
city2 | company1 | building5
city2 | company1 | building6
city2 | company2 | building7
city2 | company2 | building7
```

And you can do whatever you want with that table.

**Second way** (using aggregate function to get list of buildings for city and company):

```
SELECT 
    cities.name, companies.name, GROUP_CONCAT(buildings.name)
FROM
    cities
LEFT JOIN
   companies ON companies.city_id = city.id
LEFT JOIN 
    buildings ON buildings.city_id = city.id
ORDER BY
    cities.name, companies.name
GROUP BY
    cities.name, companies.name
```

This way Rezult should be smth like that:

```
city1 | company1 | building1, building2
city1 | company2 | building3
city2 | company1 | building4, building5, building6
city2 | company2 | building7, building8
```

**NOTE**  Name of aggregate function (GROUP_CONCAT - for MySQL) differs in DBMSes. In firebird, for example, it is "LIST"